# PHPmailer how to send to 2 emails from html form inputs when one is blank

Tags: phpmailer

I am sending email from a form with 2 email address inputs where either or both may be used or not. When I leave the second one blank, though, I get an error message. I assume it is because I am not validating the second one. But if I add the code to validate the second one then no email is sent because it gets aborted. I think I am not understanding the concept of how to do this.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Invalid address: (addAnAddress cc): ' in /var/www/html/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php:869 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php(821): PHPMailer->addOrEnqueueAnAddress('cc', '', '') #1 /var/www/html/innoedit.php(71): PHPMailer->addCC('') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 869

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
  $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
  ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
  class phpmailerAppException extends phpmailerException {}
  try {
    $to = $responsiblepost;
    if(!PHPMailer::validateAddress($to)) {
      throw new phpmailerAppException("Email address " . $to . " is invalid -- aborting!");
    }

    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
      'ssl' => array(
      'verify_peer' => false,
      'verify_peer_name' => false,
      'allow_self_signed' => true
      )
    );
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->Host       = "smtp.example.com";
$mail->Port       = "25";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "none";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = "noreply@example.com";
$mail->Password   = "password";
$mail->addReplyTo("andrew@example.com");
$mail->setFrom("noreply@example.com");
$mail->addAddress($to); //from first <input>
$mail->addAddress($informedpost); //from second <input>
$mail->Subject  = "subject";
$body = "<html>...
```

Comment: I cant see any declaration for this `$informedpost`

Comment: correct, but if I add the validateAddress thing for it then it aborts sending any email if the input field is not filled in

Comment: Check both values *before* trying to use them - handling it as an exception like that is quite cumbersome, especially since your `try` block doesn't include the `send` call. That error message doesn't line up with your code - you're not calling `addCC`. Why are you disabling SSL verification? `"none"` is not a valid value for `SMTPSecure`; use `false` if you want to disable it, though be aware of PHPMailer's auto-TLS. Your error message is vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: No SSL because it is an intranet site that does not have any world wild web interface. I will try checking them first.